# How to determine the size of the complete game tree for basic [M]?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, symmetry, combinatorial-game-theory, sudoku

You can read [the rules of the game here](http://www.fundamentalcombinatronics.com/rules-of-m/), or actually play it free on the mobile [mbrane app](http://mbranegame.com/), but it's not required to address the question.

Essentially: players take turns placing integers onto an empty Sudoku until no more integers may be legally placed.

Part of the complete gametree involves ~6.67x10²¹ complete Sudoku, reduced for rotation but not substitution because the integers have magnitude.

*(Full disclosure: this part of the tree is almost entirely meaningless as strategic placement of the integers, influenced by the topology, seems to always result in incompletable Sudoku, which leads to the real problem.)*

Here is an image to illustrate how the dead sectors occur, for those interested. (x's mark the dead sectors):

[image: Typical basic [M] game displaying dead sectors]

At some point I plan to figure out how to derive total number of broken Sudoku--dead sectors can be created with as few as 9 placements--but for now I just want to make sure I understand how the exponential expansion of placement sequence interacts mathematically with the factorial structure of Sudoku, and the proper notation.

- What is the size of the basic [M] gametree, assuming only completable Sudoku?

Alternately:

- How to derive the complete gametree size of basic [M] on a 2x2(2x2) gameboard?

The second example on 2x2(2x2) can actually be checked!

Sorry if this is a really basic question, but I only have basic maths, so be kind!  *(I'm working up to a question on how to determine the complexity class of the basic game:)*

Comment: Nice nym, Duke.

Comment: I'm currently migrating my pencil&paper work on the first two plies for 2x2(2x2) into a spreadsheet *(sure, it's easy to program, but I'm taking a cue from Euler and doing as much as possible by hand. Fun!)*  I will add a link, to show the work when it's ready.  I'm not confident about my attempts at equations however, and as the 3x3(3x3) is going to be difficult even by brute force, I'm trying to get a better grasp of the math and notation.  Also comparing the 2-ply 2x2(2x2) to the first 2 plies for 4x4 Tic-Tac-Toe & Go, which seem to be identical.

Comment: If we want to count only games that involve "complete" sudoku boards, we can take the completed sudokus and count the sequences of moves that produce such a board.  You wish to reduce this number by reflections, rotations, and (I'm assuming) interchanges of rows and columns that preserve the subsquares, but not by permutation of the numeric magnitudes of entries.  If it's agreeable, I'll post such reduced counts and we can compare in the $4\times 4$ case to your pencil-and-paper results.

Comment: @hardmath that would definitely be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If two completed $k^2\times k^2$ sudoku boards are equivalent by virtue of the allowed symmetries (the dihedral symmetries of a square plus swaps of two rows or two columns within the range of a $k$-sub-square), then any game leading to one such square is equivalent to a game (with appropriately permuted moves) leading to the other such square.

Therefore the counting of nonequivalent game sequences that lead to completed sudoku boards is the number of nonequivalent complete sudoku boards times the permutations of entries (moves) in a board.  The latter is $(k^4)!$.

**Sketch (to be expanded)** For $k=2$ there are exactly six nonequivalent completed sudoku boards.  In brief the possible completed boards are equivalent to one of the two forms:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & b & c \\
b & c & 1 & a \\
a & 1 & c & b \\
c & b & a & 1 \end{bmatrix} \;\;\;\;
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & c & b \\
b & c & 1 & a \\
a & 1 & b & c \\
c & b & a & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

where $a,b,c$ are a permutation of $2,3,4$.  The instances of one form are never equivalent to instances of the other form (easily checked by considering the determinants of the four $2\times 2$ sub-squares), but we don't get six nonequivalent boards of each form, only three.

This is because in the left form, choosing $c$ leaves $a,b$ to pick, but $a,b$ can be swapped by allowed symmetries.  So choosing $c$ gives the representative three cases.

In the right form, choosing $a$ leaves $b,c$ to pick, but $b,c$ can be swapped by allowed symmetries.  So choosing $a$ gives the representative three cases.

It follows that there are $6 = 3+3$ nonequivalent completed $4\times 4$ sudoku boards, and thus the count of nonequivalent $4\times 4$ game sequences:

$$ 6\cdot 16! \approx 1.26\times 10^{14} $$

Comment: Thank you.  This is extraordinarily useful for me.  (Now I have to go back and check the answer.  6 is familiar from my previous reading on 2x2(2x2),  and since there are only 288 non-reducible grids, I'm going to work it out by hand as I review the math.)  That's a very high number--Sei and Kawashima enumerated 3,047,783 possible positions in solving 4×4 Go, and Go has more rules. But as I work out the third step by hand, I'm getting a demonstration of how this happens. It's funny that [M] is so relatively easy to play, and the solution to [M] 2x2(2x2) so trivial.

Comment: There may be a snag.  Because [M] is partisan sudoku, and involves scoring, ownership of the integers is a differentiator.  Here is a quick breakdown of my reasoning, with examples: [M_Partisan_Sudoku_Expansion.pdf](http://www.fundamentalcombinatronics.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/M_Partisan_Sudoku_Expansion.pdf).  Am I correct that I need to identify the number of unique, "bipolar" combinations, and use that as the basis?

Comment: My count reflects the number of different games that can be played.  Of course some games may have the same score, but I don't take the Question as posted to ask about differentiating the number of scores.  In any case two games that have different scores are already differentiated in my count.  I checked your write-up, but it doesn't signify to me that any player is restricted in a move as to which number of which (empty) entry they can choose.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm very grateful for your instruction and answer.  I just need to determine if it represents the proto-gametree for ways to fill in a 2x2(2x2) Sudoku puzzle, as opposed to the gametree for M.  *(I'm doing a new doc that shows the permutations of the 6 unique Sudoku, but because of the M scoring wrinkle, I'm not sure it M can so reduced.  I'll post when I have it.)*   Again, thanks for taking the time--I'm starting from the position of "knowing nothing" so this is enormously helpful.

Comment: My thought is that scoring is well-defined by the sequence of moves, so no information is lost and none needs to be added to determine the score at the end of a game.

Comment: Perhaps your concern is that scoring is not preserved by the symmetries I'm applying to the board.   It seems to me that the scoring goes by sub-squares, and the symmetries keep all the entries in a sub-square together.  But the order of the sub-squares can be rearranged.  For example taking the matrix transpose swaps two of them and leaves the other two where they were.  Does this affect scoring?

Comment: In the basic game, there's an extra step: after all integers that can be placed, have been placed, regions "resolve" in order of the greatest disparity (delta). When a region resolves, it is awarded to the dominant player (player with the most points in the region) and all enemy integers defect (flip to the dominant player), transferring points.  This continues until all regions have been resolved. The player with the most regions wins (although there is also "strength of victory", potentially 4/0, 3/1, 3/0, 2/1, 2/0, etc., and "efficiency ratings", such as points_expended/regions_won.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72241/discussion-between-dukezhou-and-hardmath).